# iterate object entries and render multiple jsx components. NOT ARRAY

Tags: reactjs

I have the following object.

```
 latest =  {
          "dinner": 1,
          "breakfast": 2,
          "lunch": 3,
        }
```

I want to render 3 components in React.
How do I iterate through this object and return a different component for each?

I tried the code below with no success. I get element type invalid.

```
const headerDataToComponents = (latest) => {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(latest)) {
    return <div key={value}>We love {key}</div>;
  }
};
```

I am calling this function from a different component.js file like this

```
 const MyStats = headerDataToComponents(latest);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Object.entries` you can create an array and return it for your component.

```js
const latest = {
          "dinner": 1,
          "breakfast": 2,
          "lunch": 3,
        }

function App() {
  const content = headerDataToComponents();
  
  return <div>{content}</div>;
}

function headerDataToComponents() {
  return Object.entries(latest).map(([key, value]) => (
    <div key={value}>We love {key}</div>
  ));
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

But, instead of calling a function like that, you can pass the object as a prop, then map directly inside of your component.

```js
const latest = {
  dinner: 1,
  breakfast: 2,
  lunch: 3,
};

function App({ data }) {
  const content = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
    <div key={value}>We love {key}</div>
  ));

  return <div>{content}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App data={latest} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I found for resolving it

```js
const  latest =  {
    "dinner": 1,
    "breakfast": 2,
    "lunch": 3,
  } 

  const name = Object.entries(latest)

  return (
    <div>
       {name.map(key => {
         return <div key={key[1]}>We love {key[0]}</div>
       })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I hope I hope it helps you